# Date being changed when updating MySQL field

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running into a weird issue where I'm posting a date in `Y-m-d` format yet it's being changed to a completely different date once I view in the actual MySQL table.

Here's the query

```
UPDATE $admins_table 
SET    expire=$expireu 
WHERE  identity='$donation_row[steam_id]
```

The expire field is what I'm having issues with. The field itself is a varchar, and the $expireu variable is always a date in `Y-m-d` format ex. `2013-11-16`

When that query is run, with the date I gave as an example above, I get a weird result in the actual MySQL table. If I go to view the table, instead of it storing `2013-11-16` it has stored `1986` as the date. No month or day, just `1986`.

I may have made a very stupid/silly mistake, but at this point I'm unsure of what I've flubbed. Any help in the right direction would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

haha, use quotes!

```
UPDATE $admins_table SET expire='$expireu' WHERE identity='$donation_row[steam_id]'
```

mysql substracts 2013-11-16 == 1986

Comment: DERP! This is the kind of error I get when I haven't stepped away for any breaks, thank you haha.

Answer (score 0):

the use of ' and " are your friends. you are passing a math problem into mysql which it is solving and then saving the result of. wrap that date in quotes.